# Display all data from database using Datalist control for a particular column only

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, datalist

This is my DataList

```
<asp:DataList ID="mydatalist" ItemStyle-CssClass="lft_c_down"  runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <div id="wholeC">
            <div id="ctop">
             <div id="lft_l">
                <div id="lft_l_top">
                   <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ipath")%>' Height="250px" Width="300px" />
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <div id="lft_l_down">
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_sid" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"sid") %>' runat="server" Visible="false" />
                   <b>Product Name:</b>
                   <asp:Label ID="lbl2" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"products") %>' runat="server" />
                   <br/>
                   <b>brand:</b>
                   <asp:Label ID="lbl1" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"brand") %>' runat="server" />
                   <br/>
                   <b>Price:</b>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"price") %>' runat="server" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="lft_r">
                    <b>Details:</b>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label2" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"description") %>' runat="server" />
              </div>
           </div>
          <div id="cdown">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tb_cmt" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="620" placeholder="comment.."  />
               <asp:Button ID="Button1"  runat="server" Text="Comment" backcolor="black" BorderStyle="None" Font-Names="Consolas" Font-Overline="False" 
                ForeColor="White" Height="34px" Width="108px" OnClick="cmt_Click" />
              <asp:Label id="lblcmt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ecomment")%>' />
           </div>
         </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:DataList>
```

As you can see the above code will display each column value once like 1 image,1product,1 brand...and 1 comment.But what i need is all the comment availabel in the database.

I tried using repeater control inside the Datalist but i guess that is not possible.
I tried:

```
<div id="cdown">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tb_cmt" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="620" placeholder="comment.."  />
               <asp:Button ID="Button1"  runat="server" Text="Comment" backcolor="black" BorderStyle="None" Font-Names="Consolas" Font-Overline="False" 
                ForeColor="White" Height="34px" Width="108px" OnClick="cmt_Click" />
               <asp:Repeater ID="repC" runat="server" >
                 <ItemTemplate>
                       <b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ecomment") %></b>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:Repeater>
           </div>
```

Which dosen't work..wrong approach maybe.So how is it possible?

**EDIT :**
*My datalist is bounded with a DataTable while is the result of merging two table.I am trying to display data from different table in the same Datalist.So I have merged two DataTable and binded that that DataTable to the DataList.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in this case you can try another approach.Instead of this approach,You can use Nested Datalist to display data from two different table.

You can see: https://unschoolingcode.wordpress.com/2014/07/22/nested-datalist-in-asp-net/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510144.aspx